# Text coming through onto overlapping div?

Tags: css, html

I have a table where each cell has some text in it. I want a div to pop up and to cover the table but when the div pops up, it covers the table's borders, but not the text. It looks as if the text in just on the div. I have played around with the background-color and opacity, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me?

P.S. I can not make the table disappear in anyway because the overlapping div will go away eventually.

Comment: You should always post your code or at least try to recreate the issue on a site like jsfiddle or CodePen.

Comment: JSFIDDLE PLZZZZZZZ DEAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't post your code, I'm going to assume the problem is somehow related to

```
z-index:*;
```

so I created a fiddle where you can change the z-index and see the difference that makes using this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
p{
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
table, div{
    width:100px;    
    height:100px;
}
div{
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    top:-100px;
    z-index:2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><p>1</p></td>
        <td><p>2</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>3</p></td>
        <td><p>4</p></td>
    </tr>    
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59VfQ/1/)

Note that for z-index to work position has to be set, like this

```
position:relative;
```

or

```
position:absolute;
```

or

```
position:fixed;
```

though I don't think fixed might fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is Not Cleared.

Any way i hope that, this what u asked for...

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
        <td>Hellossss
            <span></span>
        </td>
         <td>English
          <span></span>
        </td>  
         <td>French
          <span></span>
        </td>          

    </tr>




</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td{ border:3px grey solid; padding:0px; position:relative; width:100px}
span{content:"";position:absolute; width:100%;height:98%; background:green; 
left:0;top:0; display:none}
td:hover span{display:block}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/edBQh/**